# Getting wrong resource name from REST API in Python script

Tags: python, rest, character-encoding, artifactory

The name of the resource in Artifactory (file management service with a GUI): "someting® bla bla.pdf"

The name returned in the Python script: "sometingÂ® bla bla.pdf"

Notice that in the Python script an additional character is added: "someting**Â**® bla bla.pdf"

The request is a basic GET request with authentication and no headers (although I did try some to explicitly set the charset).

Tried running the same request through Postman and there the response is valid.
I'm out of ideas on what might cause this to happen.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thnx

Comment: UTF-8 is being served, but the client is decoding it as latin-1, either as a fallback because the server doesn't specify the charset or because they are specified but the client ignores them.

Comment: Thank you, that is indeed the case. The solution was to try different encodings for each resource.

Using both "utf-8", "ISO-8859-1".